# Cakephp hasMany not JOINing tables

Tags: sql, cakephp, has-many

I have three tables `jobs`,`categories` and `job_categories` with similar to below structure:

```
 **jobs**

 id title desc


**categories**
id name

**job_categories**
id job_id category_id
```

So I want to retrieve all the jobs belongs to a particular category. For that I wrote an action `view()` in `CategoriesController.php`

```
function view($category_id =  NULL)
    {
          if($category_id != NULL)
          {
              $conditions['JobCategory']['category_id'] = $category_id; 
              $all_jobs = $this->Job->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions));
              $this->set('all_jobs',$all_jobs);
          }
    }
```

And added a `$hasMany` to `Category.php` model:

```
class Category extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Category';
    var $hasMany = array('JobCategory');
}
```

But when I checked the view , it shows error:

`Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'JobCategory' in 'where clause'` and the query it generates :

> SELECT `Job`.`id`, `Job`.`job_title`, `Job`.`job_description`,
>   `Job`.`job_skills`, `Job`.`contact_number`, `Job`.`contact_email`,
>   `Job`.`qualification_id`, `Job`.`experience`, `Job`.`categories`,
>   `Job`.`remarks`, `Job`.`support_image`, `Job`.`freshers_apply`,
>   `Job`.`added_on`, `Job`.`status`, `Qualification`.`id`,
>   `Qualification`.`name` FROM `cakead`.`jobs` AS `Job` LEFT JOIN
>   `cakead`.`qualifications` AS `Qualification` ON
>   (`Job`.`qualification_id` = `Qualification`.`id`) WHERE JobCategory =
>   ('1')

Answer (score 0):

try this

//AppModel.php

```
public $actAs = array('Containable');
```

//Category.php

```
class Category extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Category';
    var $hasAndBelongsTo = array('Category');
}
```

//CategoriesController.php

```
function view($category_id =  NULL)
    {
          if($category_id != NULL)
          {
              $conditions['Category']['id'] = $category_id; 
              $all_jobs = $this->Category->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions));
              $this->set('all_jobs',$all_jobs);
          }
    }
```